# Python modules no longer importing

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have been writing a program for several weeks involving the use of several packages including scipy and cv2. Today the program stopped importing most of the modules. Some are OK, such as numpy and pandas, but many have just stopped importing, giving rise to an import error in the command line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Michael, we will need more details... can you supply us some screenshots ? code sample ?

Comment: try checking whether you are not using any virtual environment. Use your system interpreter for Python